# How to map a class as immutable using FluentNHibernate?

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

How can I map a class as immutable using FluentNHibernate. Using hbm I can do like this.

```
<class name="Namespace.YYYY" table="XXXX" mutable="false" >
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Fluent NHibernate: How to map an entire class as ReadOnly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2871251/fluent-nhibernate-how-to-map-an-entire-class-as-readonly)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try this link: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2871277/1679310

summary:

```
class EntityMap : ClassMap<Entity>
{
    public EntityMap()
    {
        ReadOnly();

        // Mappings
    }
}
```