# FluentNHibernate SubclassMap set entire class ReadOnly

Tags: c#, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate-mapping

I have a Class that I want to set readonly using Fluent NHibernate.

On a normal ClassMap this can be [done](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2871251/fluent-nhibernate-how-to-map-an-entire-class-as-readonly).

But I can find no way of doing this on a Subclass without moving all the mapping into the subclass and no longer using inheritance.

Maybe there is a better way to do what I'm doing?